# Confusion regarding logical AND in Python

Tags: python, operators, boolean-logic

The following is a toy example in Python:

```
a = 2
b= 10
result = a<b and print("Hello")
print(bool(result))
```

The output is:

```
Hello
False
```

Why is the output `False` instead of `True`? Since `result` evaluates to `a<b= 2<10 = True` then, we have `result = True and print()` = `True and True` = `True`. Can somebody please explain the reason for this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` returns `None`:

```
>>> print("Hello") is None
True
```

and `None` is a `False`y value:

```
>>> bool(None)
False
```

so you have `True and False`, which evaluates to `False`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. One thing is unclear, could you please clarify? In the first line, why is the output True after the print statement when you do mention that print is equivalent to None or False? What is meant by `print() is None` which is True?

Comment: What `print` returns is the value `None`. Then we check `is` it really `None`: and yes it is and we see `True`. @Sm1

Comment: `is` operator checks for identity. You can also check here with `==` but since `None` is a singletone, idiomatic is to check with `is`. Also you can write these in separate lines maybe it helps more: `print_result = print("Hello")` and then `print_result == None` (or `is`). @Sm1

Comment: In short, `print` returns something that, when evaluated in boolean context, gives `False`. As an extra, that *something* it returns is `None` (kind of null in other languages).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. THis behavior is quite different from C where the print would return True -- there is no none and that makes the final answer in C as `result = True and True = True` . This is different than what Python gives for this example!

Comment: @Sm1 Indeed! Though, `printf("")` would return 0 and that'd be `False`. But python's `print` returns `None` regardless of the input argument...

Comment: Thank you again for discussing about C: Just a last clarification--could you kindly say why `printf()` would be false in C? So would python and C give same or different result for this expression?

Comment: @Sm1 `printf` returns the number of characters printed to the screen. So it returns a nonegative integer. The edge case is when you don't print any character at all! i.e., if you do `int rv = printf("");` then `rv` will have value 0. And integer 0 is evaluated as `False` in boolean context in C (and also in Python but not important). In any other case, when you do print some character, `rv` will be some positive integer e.g. 5 for `int rv = printf("Hello");`. And 5 is `True` in boolean context.

Comment: In short, Python's `print`'s return value will be *always* `False` when `bool`ed. C's `printf` will be `False` *only when* you print no character at all. Otherwise it will be `True` in boolean context. @Sm1